# Remote push notification doesn't wake up my phone

Tags: ios

I use remote push notification with content available key set to 1 which , from
apple documentation, it has to wake up the device, but it doesn't work properly, sometimes the device doesn't wake up.
I use this mechanism to send device location to our server. 
Why remote push notification doesn't wake up my device all the time ?

I use app delegate method didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler, which from apple documentation should be called when the app is running in the foreground or background. Also I enabled the remote notifications background mode so when a remote notification is received the system should put my app in background state and I should have 30s to perform my task in response to push notification.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean by "wake up device"

Comment: I added extra explanation. By "wake up device" I mean the system should put my app in background state and get 30s time to perfrom some actions whitout user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Push notifications do not wake up apps in certain cases

1. If the user rebooted his device and never launched the app since the reboot, the app will not wake up remotely
2. If the user killed the app manually from the app switcher, the app will also not wake up remotely

Comment: Yes, 2 is correct but 1 I'm not so sure, apple documentation says something else.
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:
See explanation for this method:
- application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:

Comment: Well yes, I've seen the documentation. But I've also run some tests with notifications and ^ is what I found/experienced

Comment: Ok, thanks for quick reply. This was I found also but I thought I miss something. Is any method to respond automatically with location when a push notification arrives?